# Python, variable is not returning correct number

Tags: python

I am building a chess engine and my variables content is not being returned properly.

```py
# ChessAI.py
global scoreres
scoreres = 0

def findBestMove(var, var2, var3):
   global next_move, scoreres
   next_move = None
   score = function(etc.) # <- function returns a score i.e. -0.9000000000000092
   scoreres = score

def getNegaScore():
   # using print(scoreres) here also returns 0
   return scoreres
```

When I print score inside findBestMove it correctly displays what I want i.e. `-0.5000000000000115`

but when I seem to use:

```py
# ChessMain.py
move_finder_process = Process(target=ChessAI.findBestMove, args=(
   game_state, valid_moves, return_queue))
move_finder_process.start()
print(ChessAI.getNegaScore()) # <- returns as 0
```

Why is `ChessAI.getNega()` being returned as 0?

I tried returning my scoreResult to my ChessMain file. Inside the function I get the correct result but when the var is asked for in either another function and/or file it returns as 0

Comment: Why not `return score` from `findBestMove()` and get rid of `getNegaScore()` altogether?

Comment: @MattDMo `findBestMove()` is being called in `Process(target=ChessAI.findBestMove etc` and the function doesnt return anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It returns 0 because, since `move_finder_process` was not started (`move_finder_process.start()`), `findBestMove` was never called

You should also wait for it to finish before retriving the result: `move_finder_process.join()`

EDIT:
I now notice that it's not using a process shared object, so `move_finder_process` has its own copy of `scoreres` and won't infuence the parent version of it

Comment: `move_finder_process.start()` is being called right under the Process. sorry, I didn't include it. I'll update it right away! Although `findBestMove` is being called like mentioned in my question. When I call the print function inside findBestMove it does return a correct answer. So the function is clearly being called

Comment: ok, is waiting for the process to finish (`.join()`) of any help?

Comment: I figured it out. by creating a new queue: `score_queue = Queue()` I was able to just simple put the result in there within the function itself. This seems to work fine